# does changing python version need rebuilding caffe

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, caffe

I used a `virtualbox` with ubuntu-16, to install caffe in python 2.6. As I wanted to use `py2exe`, I needed to change python version to 3.6.  When this was done, caffe import code stopped working. Here is the error message:

```
ImportError: libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc5: cannot open shared object file: No such file  
or directory
```

Do I have to rebuild caffe? Or is something else that need to be changed?

Here is the full image of the error:

[image: Here is the full image of the error]

Comment: @Inman  thankyou for improve my question. and i tried to rebuid caffe again, but there was a new problem. when ran the caffe requires.txt, the system got a error : [unable to execute /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory], my pip is in conda3 folder.   so thanks for any advice

Comment: **$ pip --version**
pip 9.0.1 from /home/nelson/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: I think i solved the question by a fast way "restored from snapshot"

Comment: That's a workaround / recovery, not a solution.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to rebuild Caffe.  The Python 2 and Python 3 libraries are not compatible.  Not all of the file names are the same (different / added software organization).  This rebuild requires that you place a single version of Python first in all search paths: make, compile, load, ...

When I need to do this, I check with my SysOps: there's always something I forget.

Comment: I think you are right, can you give some advice on how to change python version quickly. some trick

Comment: The "quick way" I know is to totally uninstall all Python versions, install Python 3, and continue from there.  Otherwise, I turn the problem over to my SysOps: in my environment, linking new software to Python 3 (instead of an existing Python 2) generally requires someone who can recognize and repair a variety of linking problems.